# How to add limit in meteor query?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I want to limit to 2 records using this query.

```
self.helpers({
        avalibility: () => {
          return SetAvalibility.find({}).fetch(2);              
        }
      })
```

And its not working,but the same in Robomongo this is working fine.

```
db.avalibility.find({}).limit(2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use meteor limit properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161000/how-to-use-meteor-limit-properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better not to use .fetch() ;)

```
avalibility: () => {
  return SetAvalibility.find({}, {limit: 2});              
}
```

Comment: I think we need to add .fetch() also 
ie;
SetAvalibility.find({}, {limit: self.pageLimit}).fetch()

Comment: Yep, you can to add .fetch() but for what?

Comment: yep, I think so ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `limit` parameter is an option of the `fetch` method:

```
SetAvalibility.find({}, {limit: 2}).fetch();
```